# MediaElement.js  works on one site but not the other?

Tags: plugins, javascript, media

I love [the MediaElement.js plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/) but I seem a little stumped. I have installed it on two WordPress sites: http://blog.mattforget.com/?p=94 and http://oedipus1.com/home/?p=3822

The sites are hosted with different providers. On `blog.mattforget.com`, in Firefox, the player looks great. It looks great just like it was inserted into Chrome, the iPhone browser, IE and safari.

On the `oedipus1.com` site however, this does not happen. I end up seeing the broken player.

My original thought was that maybe a mime type of some sort was not active on the `oedipus1.com` site that allows the plugin to work correctly, or that there is something conflicting with the plugin that is not allowing the player to show correctly.

Regardless of my thoughts, I'd like to run this past you to see if by looking at the two sites or maybe from your past experience, you may be able to tell me what the issue is.

Could you let me know if there is something I am missing? I would appreciate it immensely.

Comment: you have a js error on the oedipus1 site: `TypeError: Result of expression '$('#wp_mep_1').mediaelementplayer' [undefined] is not a function.`

Answer (score 2):

The site that doesn't work is loading jQuery twice. remove the one included by your theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.oedipus1.com/home/wp-content/themes/GrungeMag/js/jquery.js"></script>
```